# SQL Greater than specific time on the previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server

A shift in our plant is defined as starting at 4am and continues until 2 am on the following day.

At 3 am on a given day I want to get all the records for the previous shift.

The query below gets me the previous day upto now but also includes 12am to 2 am on the "previous previous" shift. How do i get the query to get data ONLY after 4am ?

```
select 
    * 
    from yourTable
    WHERE TimeStamp >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using? (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL...)

Comment: @danjuggler sql server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATE = GETDATE()-1
DECLARE @time TIME = '04:00:00'
DECLARE @shiftstart DATETIME = CAST(@yesterday AS DATETIME) + CAST(@time AS DATETIME) 

select 
    * 
    from yourTable
    WHERE TimeStamp >= @shiftstart
```

Comment: So simple and efficient.

Comment: You flatter me.  Just here to help.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is to subtract 2 hours from the shift time and use the date portion.  A simplistic implementation is:

```
where cast(dateadd(hour, -2, TimeStamp) as date) = cast(dateadd(day, -1, GetDate()) as date)
```

Sometimes, it is more efficient to do all the arithmetic on the "constant" (i.e. `getdate()`):

```
where TimeStamp >= dateadd(hour, 2, cast(GetDate() as Date))
```

Note:  the appropriate function for this logic is `dateadd()` not `datediff()`.